# Java / Hibernate Timestamp being affected by daylight savings despite UTC

Tags: java, postgresql, time, timezone, dst

I am querying from Postgres into Java.

I have set both Postgres and Java to use 'UTC'.

However when i do a query for some reason the date is being affected by daylight savings jump.

I set hibernate to UTC. (pom.xml).

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
</properties>
```

I have my postgres timezone set to UTC.
timezone = 'UTC'  (restarted service)
When i query postgres i dont get the issue.
In addition when I manually set a date in java and then increment i do not get the issue.

It appears to be only when i query and use hibernate for some reason that it "ignores" UTC for some brief period of time and skips the hour.

I may be able to do drastic things like using char vs timestamp in the database so hibernate isnt confused but this seems drastic i must be missing something simple?

Update: So moving all logic to a stored procedure and doing it there solved the issue.  I would go as far as to say this could be a bug with hibernate. I have it set hibernate to use UTC which should exclude timezones?

Comment: Unfortunately, some tooling and middleware likes to apply a time zone to the value retrieved from the database. Postgres only stores a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in UTC, always UTC.

Answer (score 1):

So after trying many things it looks like doing:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Works like some SO threads suggest

However doing:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Duser.timezone=UTC</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
</properties>
```

does nothing.  I have seen many SO threads suggesting the property change in the JVM but in my experience only the TimeZone.setDefault does anything.